# Ajax request does not preserve full URL (protocol) provided in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have ajaxified some of my views but for some reason it does not preserve `https` and tries to redirect to `http`. I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
  var polling_url = "#{eligibility_check_polling_phone_details_url}";
  var redirect_url = "#{eligibility_check_result_phone_details_url}";

  var checkResult = function() {
    $.getJSON(polling_url, function(result) {
      if(result.complete) location.href = redirect_url;
      else setTimeout(checkResult, 2000);
    });
  };

  // some more stuff
});
```

as you can see I am providing the URL but it still blocks the request as it is redirected to `http` which is not allowed since XSS.

Thanks

Edit: Apparently `#{eligibility_check_result_phone_details_url}` returns `http:` for some reason, while all other URLs are `https:`

Comment: Assuming `console.log(redirect_url)` returns a https URL, can you post your server log from when that redirect is taking place?

Comment: @NickM redirect_url actually is `http:` only when doing a log there, weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, since `console.log('redirect_url')` returns a `http` link, all you have to do is replace the protocol with Javascript:

```
var https_redirect_url  = redirect_url.replace("http", "https");
if(result.complete) location.href = https_redirect_url;
```

If Rails was performing the redirect you would see a redirect in the server log.

If you want all your routes/helpers to be `https` you can add this to `routes.rb`

`default_url_options protocol: :https`

Also, you can do this at the controller/namespace level if you only want to restrict certain controllers to `https`:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?

  def ssl_configured?
    !Rails.env.development?
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks but would this be a security concern as someone could replace it back to http?

Comment: Not necessarily. They could do that by typing http into their address bar, so I wouldn't worry about it. If you want to force HTTPS across your entire app that's another question